Qt quick layout which fills parent window and has margins
I am trying to use a Column layout which fills the ApplicationWindow parent. I want the window to have content padding, so I guess I have to put margin to the layout. This is the approach I am taking:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    width: rootLayout.implicitWidth
    height: rootLayout.implicitHeight
    minimumWidth: rootLayout.Layout.minimumWidth
    minimumHeight: rootLayout.Layout.minimumHeight

    ColumnLayout {
        id: rootLayout
        anchors.margins: 10
        anchors.fill: parent
   }
}

But it does not work fine since the minimum height property of the layout does not take into account the margins and the window can shrink more than it should be possible.

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    visible: true

    width: minimumWidth
    height: minimumHeight

    minimumWidth: rootLayout.implicitWidth + rootLayout.anchors.margins*2
    minimumHeight: rootLayout.implicitHeight + rootLayout.anchors.margins*2

    ColumnLayout {
        id: rootLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
   }
}

Also note, that you must also fill ColumnLayout with some real elements with correctly defined implicit sizes for the everything to be sized properly.

I have been able to do it by adding the margin into the minimum size calculations of the window:
minimumWidth: rootLayout.Layout.minimumWidth + rootLayout.anchors.margins * 2
minimumHeight: rootLayout.Layout.minimumHeight + rootLayout.anchors.margins * 2

I find it a bit tricky and I am getting random error messages when resizing the window:
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 1316x776+1292+656 (frame: 1338x832+1281+611) on Main_QMLTYPE_0/"" on "DELL U2723QE". Resulting geometry: 1316x806+1292+656 (frame: 1338x862+1281+611) margins: 11, 45, 11, 11 minimum size: 453x537 MINMAXINFO(maxSize=POINT(x=0, y=0), maxpos=POINT(x=0, y=0), maxtrack=POINT(x=0, y=0), mintrack=POINT(x=702, y=862)))
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 1208x812+1292+656 (frame: 1230x868+1281+611) on Main_QMLTYPE_0/"" on "DELL U2723QE". Resulting geometry: 1208x842+1292+656 (frame: 1230x898+1281+611) margins: 11, 45, 11, 11 minimum size: 453x561 MINMAXINFO(maxSize=POINT(x=0, y=0), maxpos=POINT(x=0, y=0), maxtrack=POINT(x=0, y=0), mintrack=POINT(x=702, y=898)))
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 1293x776+1292+656 (frame: 1315x832+1281+611) on Main_QMLTYPE_0/"" on "DELL U2723QE". Resulting geometry: 1293x806+1292+656 (frame: 1315x862+1281+611) margins: 11, 45, 11, 11 minimum size: 453x537 MINMAXINFO(maxSize=POINT(x=0, y=0), maxpos=POINT(x=0, y=0), maxtrack=POINT(x=0, y=0), mintrack=POINT(x=702, y=862)))
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 1277x812+1292+656 (frame: 1299x868+1281+611) on Main_QMLTYPE_0/"" on "DELL U2723QE". Resulting geometry: 1277x842+1292+656 (frame: 1299x898+1281+611) margins: 11, 45, 11, 11 minimum size: 453x561 MINMAXINFO(maxSize=POINT(x=0, y=0), maxpos=POINT(x=0, y=0), maxtrack=POINT(x=0, y=0), mintrack=POINT(x=702, y=898)))
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 1289x776+1292+656 (frame: 1311x832+1281+611) on Main_QMLTYPE_0/"" on "DELL U2723QE". Resulting geometry: 1289x806+1292+656 (frame: 1311x862+1281+611) margins: 11, 45, 11, 11 minimum size: 453x537 MINMAXINFO(maxSize=POINT(x=0, y=0), maxpos=POINT(x=0, y=0), maxtrack=POINT(x=0, y=0), mintrack=POINT(x=702, y=862)))


The warnings arise because your minimumWidth/Height and width/height are too small (in your example, width/height are zero and minimumWidth/Height are 20), which should be greater than the window's frame size.
